# Rails - link_to method is accidentally(?) being triggered on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, routes, link-to

I am very new to Rails, heads up! I am required to use these versions for the time being:

Rails: 3.2.18

Ruby: 1.9.3-p194

Whenever I call a custom method `destroy_session` from a `link_to` button,  it seems to be working fine. However, whenever I manually refresh the page `session[:session_token]` is cleared, as if the `destroy_session` method was called... I'm not sure why?

If I completely remove the `<link_to>` button from the View, the `session[:session_token]` **remains intact as expected** no matter how many times I refresh the browser. Here's my current workflow to elaborate further:

- Click "Get Token" button makes an AJAX request and stores response in `session[:session_token]`
- The view is refreshed and the session token is written to the screen, as expected.
- If I hit refresh in the browser manually, the session token disappears as if I called the `destroy_session` method.

**View**
*/app/views/searches/index.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', action: destroy_session_path %>
```

**Controller**
*/app/controllers/searches_controller.rb*

```
helper_method :destroy_session

def destroy_session
  session[:session_token] = nil
end
```

**Routes**
*/config/routes.rb*

```
resources :searches
match '/searches/destroy_session' => 'searches#destroy_session', :as => :destroy_session
post '/searches/get_token' => 'searches#get_token'
root :to => 'searches#index'
```

**$ rake routes**

```
          searches GET    /searches(.:format)                 searches#index
                   POST   /searches(.:format)                 searches#create
        new_search GET    /searches/new(.:format)             searches#new
       edit_search GET    /searches/:id/edit(.:format)        searches#edit
            search GET    /searches/:id(.:format)             searches#show
                   PUT    /searches/:id(.:format)             searches#update
                   DELETE /searches/:id(.:format)             searches#destroy
   destroy_session        /searches/destroy_session(.:format) searches#destroy_session
          ajax_sum POST   /ajax/sum(.:format)                 my#ajax_sum
searches_get_token POST   /searches/get_token(.:format)       searches#get_token
              root        /                                   searches#index
```

No errors or exceptions are thrown. Would someone please help me identify what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [`link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) documentation.

Method should be an HTTP verb, not a method name. Call controllers method to destroy your session.

Example:

```
link_to "Some Text", :controller => :searches, :action => :destroy_session
```

Comment: You should probably had put actual method and controller name in example as OP has posted for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nikita! I seem to be getting the same error all the way around:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SearchesController#show
Couldn't find Search with id=destroy_session

Comment: @ndcomix: Put line: `match '/searches/destroy_session' => 'searches#destroy_session'` below `resources :searches` in your routes.rb and then try again.

Comment: Surya, that line was already in my routes file. I moved it directly under resources :searches (it was several lines beneath it) but nothing changed unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', method: destroy_session %>
```

When ruby is reading this line, it will read:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', method: nil %>
```

because you execute `destroy_session` method here, which, naturally, destroys session. What you probably meant was:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', action: :destroy_session %>
```

Note it is a symbol, not a method call. Also note that destroy_session needs to be an action, not the helper method.

It would be best if you however name you route (server restart required):

```
match '/searches/destroy_session' => 'searches#destroy_session', as: :destroy_session
```

And use url helper:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', action: destroy_session_path %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `action: :destroy_session` alone will work? I think it will work only if you're on `/searches/..` i.e. on one of the searches controller method. I may not be correct though, never tried.

Comment: If i remeber correctly, if controller is missing it will use the current controller.

Comment: Hi BroiSatse, thank you for your help! I've tried your approach, but whenever I click the button :destroy_action is not called and I'm redirected to the 'show' view with the following exception:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SearchesController#show
Couldn't find Search with id=destroy_session

Comment: @BroiSatse: That's what I meant in my first comment, thanks for clarifying it.

Comment: @BroiSatse I've updated my post above to reflect the code changes. I've restarted the server too, jic. Currently I'm getting a routing error whenever I try to view the site:

No route matches {:action=>"/searches/destroy_session", :controller=>"searches"}

I ran $rake routes and it looks like the destroy_session is there... I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

which rails do you use?
try to set in routes.rb:

```
get '/searches/destroy_session' => 'searches#destroy_session'
```

and then

```
<%= link_to 'Delete Token', searches_destroy_session_path %>
```

maybe it will help

Comment: That'll not work unless you explicitly define the routing helper method name: `get '/searches/destroy_session' => 'searches#destroy_session', :as => :searches_destroy_session`

Comment: Thank you for the help Marko! I'm using Rails: 3.2.18 and Ruby: 1.9.3-p194

I tried this approach (with and without Surya's suggestion) and am getting this error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SearchesController#show
Couldn't find Search with id=destroy_session

Comment: you are somehow being redirected to show action. try to add redirection to root after `session[:session_token] = nil` in your method `def destroy_session`. also, try to remove this `helper_method :destroy_session`

Comment: Marko, I've tried redirecting but no luck. The destroy_session def doesn't appear to get called at all, thus no redirection is executed inline. :/ I've updated my code above to reflect some changes... I feel like we're getting close! (I've also removed the helper_method, with no apparent effect that I can tell)